# How do you transform the following in an implication?

Tags: logic

So, I have :

If the moon is made of green cheese, then cows jump over it.

The moon is made of green cheese.

Therefore, cows jump over the moon.

How would I transform this as a logical implication ? Is it possible ? Thank you!

Comment: the moon is made of green cheese $\implies$ cows jump over the moon

Comment: Wait we can do this ? (I feel like a fool now...) What about the "If the moon is made of green cheese, then cows jump over it." and "The moon is made of green cheese." ???

Comment: For fun look up "What The Tortoise Said To Achilles" by Charles L.Dodgson (a.k.a. Lewis Carroll).

Answer (score 0):

(  ((Green cheese) $\implies$ (Cows)),...  and ... (Green cheese)   ) $\implies$ (Cows).

Answer (score 0):

Question: Is it "some cows" or "all cows"?

Assuming it's "some cows" then,

---

Variable: $c: \text{ a thing}$

Constants: $m:\text{ the moon}$

Set : $C:\text{ cows}$

Predicates: $G(x): x\text{ is made of green cheese}, \\ J(x, y) : x\text{ jumps over }y$

Statement: $G(m)\to (\exists c\in C: J(c,m)) ,\, G(m) \;\vdash\; \exists c\in C: J(c,m)$